# JSON won't fetch in angular

Tags: angularjs, json, html

**edit:** I've updated the code with the latest changes you guys proposed.

I have this data.json:

```
[{
"codigo": 21420,
"desc": "itv orion 20 a",
"prod_24_h_kg": 22
}, {
"codigo": 21421,
"desc": "itv orion 20 w",
"prod_24_h_kg": 24
}, {
"codigo": 21430,
"desc": "itv orion 30 a",
"prod_24_h_kg": 31
}, {
"codigo": 21431,
"desc": "itv orion 30 w",
"prod_24_h_kg": 34
}, {
"codigo": 21440,
"desc": "itv orion 40 a",
"prod_24_h_kg": 40
}, {
"codigo": 21441,
"desc": "itv orion 40 w",
"prod_24_h_kg": 42
}, {
"codigo": 21460,
"desc": "itv orion 60 a",
"prod_24_h_kg": 54
}, {
"codigo": 21461,
"desc": "itv orion 60 w",
"prod_24_h_kg": 56
}, {
"codigo": 21480,
"desc": "itv orion 80 a",
"prod_24_h_kg": 77
}, {
"codigo": 21481,
"desc": "itv orion 80 w",
"prod_24_h_kg": 79
 }, {
"codigo": 21490,
"desc": "itv orion 130 a",
"prod_24_h_kg": 130
}]
```

In app.js I have this:

```
$scope.people = [];
$scope.loadData = function() {
  alert("2");
  $http.get('data.json').then(function(data) {
    alert("succ");
    console.log(data)
    $scope.people = data.maq;
  });
};
```

Also, this is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <p> Click <a ng-click="loadData()">here</a> to load data.</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
      <td>{{person.codigo}}</td>
      <td>{{person.desc}}</td>
      <td>{{person.prod_24_h_kg}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

So, when I click I do get the alert from the function, however the data won't load; I get no errors either.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I thought it wa a cross origin problem, but the json is on the same domain and I don't get the error. I'm running a local server with XAMPP.

Comment: Where does the 'data.json' is located ?

Comment: You can add line `console.log("data")` inside callback function. This way you would see in console what is actually being loaded.

Comment: Accessing local file with $http.get

Comment: The data.json is in the www directory, where the index.html is located.

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: it's not part of your issue but you should replace `.success` (deprecated) to `.then`

Comment: I get success answer. Also, this is the console.log: http://i.imgur.com/HT8R2Mp.png

Comment: try ` $scope.people = data.maq;`

Comment: Nothing has changes with all the changes. http://i.imgur.com/1Zh24l8.png

Comment: could you make a plunker or similar ?, it'll be easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<table ng-if="people">`

And based on your last print there's a data inside your object so it should be:
`$scope.people = data.data.maq;`

Comment: data.data did the trick, I thank you very much for seeing it and helpig me out. I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thanks to everyone else as well. I'll update the code ASAP. Didn't add the maq, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. line 101 `"codigo": 21441,` might start with `{` ?
verify with some online json validor http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The JSON is valid, I just cut it down short and  made a mistake. I validated it on jsonlint.com.